# 2 Identical Fixtures with LED Bulbs only work when one has regular bulbs in it (PICTURE)

Tags: light-fixture, led

I bought two light fixtures with 4 bulb slots, each, to replace two fluorescent lights. I also bought LED bulbs that can be controlled using an LED remote for those fixtures.

**The issue** One of the fixtures, with 4 LED bulbs, only works if the other fixture has two non LED bulbs plugged in, even tho the non led bulbs don't turn on. If I take out one of the non LED bulbs, the non LED that's left begins to flash.

If I have all 8 LED bulbs plugged in, then I have no color control of the LED bulbs and they begin to flash. I can show it on video if anyone needs any specifics. It seems like there is too much or too little power coming through and the fixtures are dependant on how much power is drawn from the other.

The previous lights were fluorescent. The new ones will be powered under the GU10 bulbs in a 2, 4 bulb tracker lighting fixtures, shown in pictures below.

https://www.ebay.com/itm/4-Light-Track-Lighting-Ceiling-Wall-Interior-Lamp-Fixture-Oil-Rubbed-Bronze-/251640124753?hash=item3a96eb9551

[image]

Please let me know if you need any more information.

Thank you!

Comment: Are both fixtures controlled by the same light switch? Is it an on/off switch, a manually-controlled dimmer switch or some type of smart switch?

Comment: what model are these LED bulbs?

Comment: @Graham - Both fixtures are controlled by the same fixtures. It's a simple on/off, not dimmable.

Comment: @Dan The lights are GU10 LED Lights, 40W. Here is the link https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0798LF5PF/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o05_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: I suspect the remote(s). They can be interfering with eachother. Do the bulbs work ok one at a time?

Comment: If you take all 4 bulbs out of one fixture do either LED or non-LED bulbs work in the other fixture?

Comment: @GrahamNye If I take the bulbs out of the first fixture that had nonLED bulbs, the wires for the other fixture do not receive any power. So it seems that the power for Fixture 2 is dependant on if power is being drawn from Fixture 1, it being with an LED or non LED bulb in Fixture 1

Comment: @dandavis The remote is a standard LED remote that works on every single other LED device in my apartment. I think it may be a voltage issue. Was thinking maybe I should change the copper wires to a larger size to bring more voltage.

Comment: No, don't mess with the wires.  That's not it.  I mean, it might be if you wired the fixtures *in series* or something, but it's definitely not a problem of "copper wires not thick enough".  Anyway, you shouldn't be wing-dinging your wire size,  you need to use the legal and correct wire size for the circuit per your government's standards.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Sorry didn't mean to say "thick enough" but going from a 12/2 to a 14/2 wire.

Comment: It sounds as if your fixtures are wired in series. You should have a black(hot) and white(neutral) wire feeding both fixtures in parallel. If you have a black wire feeding one fixture and the other power connection on that fixture is connected to the other fixture (indeterminate color) which is then connected to a white wire then they are in series and the bulbs aren't getting enough voltage. Was the old fixture actually fluorescent (e.g. did it flicker when switched on) or are you using that as a generic term for a straight strip light? What markings are on the bulbs in the old fixture. ...

Comment: Are the old bulbs marked for 60 V operation?

Comment: @GrahamNye Unfortunately, I don't have the old fixture or the bulbs as everything was demolished. The old light looked like a regular tube fluorescent light. The apartment was built in '89 hence my assumption. 

In terms of wiring, the hot wire in one fixture is blue and the neutral is black as it reads no voltage when turned on. For fixture 2, the hot wire is black and the white wire is neutral. How would I be able to fix the lack of voltage?

Comment: I'm afraid I have to leave now. I hope someone else will be able to pick up the trail.

Comment: No worries, thank you so much for your help! Really appreciate it.

Comment: Back again. Demolition sounds drastic. I assumed you (or someone else) had simply removed  two working fluorescent lights and replaced them with your GU10 fixtures in the same locations without changing the fixed wiring feeding the lights. Demolition suggests some further work was carried out, perhaps disturbing the fixed wiring. Was that the case? I'm also assuming you're in the US from your mention of amazon.com and 12/2 & 14/2 wires. A blue wire can be used for 3-way switching [(e.g. here)](https://www.electrical101.com/3way-switch-wiring-using-nm-cable.html).  ...

Comment: ... You suggested you now have a single light switch controlling your 2 new fixtures. Were the previous 2  fluorescent lights controlled from switches in 2 different locations?

Comment: Pictures. If you want to have any hope of someone here being able to help you, provide clear, focused labeled pictures. Pics of: 1) The switch(s) that are supposed to control the lights. 2) The wiring inside the junction box(es) that the lights are supposed to connect to. 3) The wiring coming out of the fixtures themselves. [Edit] these into your original question and _also_ provide the exact make/model of the light fixtures themselves (if it's mentioned in the comments, nobody's going to read 30+ comments to find it).

Comment: Hey guys! Sorry been very busy lately, but I added a picture with details on what my situation looks like. If you need any more detailed pics, please let me know. 

@GrahamNye Yes, I am in the US. You are correct, no wiring was changed after the flourecent lights were taken out. The new GU10 fixture was put in. Should there have been changes made to the wiring?

Also, the fluorescent lights were controlled by one switch, no other location.

Comment: "Should there have been changes made to the wiring?" No. You should be able to remove old working lights, fit new lights and have them work without changing the fixed wiring. I asked to check whether any demolition/remodelling work had affected the wiring. Other people may be able to help if you provide close-up pictures of the wiring to the 2 fixtures and of the switch. However I've run out of suggestions I'm prepared to offer and if no one else has any ideas my final suggestion is to get an electrician in.